# Database Error Name Not getting fetched

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            input
            {
                position:relative;
                height:5%;
                width:25%;
                border:2px solid;
                background-color:#219869;
                border-radius:10px;
                font-weight:bold;
                text-align:center;
                font-size:19px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor='#b5eff5'>
        <form method="POST" action='criminal_search.php'>
            <select name='s1'>
                <option value="ID">ID</option>
                <option value="Name">Name</option>
                <option value="Phone Number">Phone Number</option>
                <option value="Date">Date</option>
            </select>
            <input type=text name='i1' id='i1'></input>
            <input type=submit value=submit name="submit"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $dbname = "policainformation";
            $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',$dbname);
            if (!$conn)
            {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            else
            {
                $option1=$_POST['s1'];
                if($option1=="ID")
                {
                    $option1="report_id";
                }
                else
                if($option1=="Name")
                {
                    $option1="reporter_name";
                }
                else
                if($option1=="Phone Number")
                {
                    $option1="reporter_ph";
                }
                else
                if($option1=="Date")
                {
                    $option1="report_date";
                }

                $option2=$_POST['i1'];
                if($option1!="Name")
                $sql="select * from criminal where $option1 in ($option2)";
                else
                $sql="select * from criminal where $option1 in '$option2'"; 
                $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No Records Found!')</script>");
                if($result)

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        echo $row["report_id"].$row["reporter_name"].$row["reporter_ph"].$row["reporter_email"].$row["reporter_address"].$row["report_date"].$row["suspect_name"].$row["reason_of_report"].$row["proof"]."<br>";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No Records Found!')</script>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

This is my HTML Code. I'm trying to retrieve values and display on the webpage. Everything is working fine except the NAME option. When i search with the name i.e when i fire a query with the name in PHP code, it does not work. It echoes no records found. Please help Me. I'm also putting the table structure for better reference.

https://gyazo.com/1c69aad3491c00d876128e198e39f176

https://screenshots.firefox.com/psi7MgWUjapXavID/localhost

Comment: `IN` function needs brackets, your second one has single quotes. What is your intended purpose of that if/else?

Comment: if else is for executing the specific query. If it is name then sql must have single quotes for text and if number then it need not have single quotes. Hence given the if else condition. But it is giving problem to the else part.

Comment: @Scuzzy It is still not working even if i put brackets

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL IN uses parenthesis () not quotes ''

```
$sql="select * from criminal where $option1 in ($option2)";
else
$sql="select * from criminal where $option1 = '$option2'";
```

Comment: Database is in mysql